# Using ini_set('memory_limit') in a php function

Tags: php, ini-set

I have a particularly memory intensive function I'd like to (just while that function is running) up the allowed memory for it to complete.

Is it poor practice to use `ini_set('memory_limit' , '1024M')` within a php function and once the function is completed will it return to default value?

I know it's a high value to use. It's a dedicated server and has plenty of juice.

Example would be:

```
function run_Cron_Processes() {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
    memoryIntensive1();
    memoryIntensive2();
    memoryIntensive3();
    //return to default m limit
}
```

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit' , 1024M) This memory limit will be set for this request on this specific page only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$oldLimit = ini_get( 'memory_limit' );
ini_set( 'memory_limit', '1024M' );
(...)
ini_set( 'memory_limit', $oldLimit );
```

But I think it is unnecessary: at the end of the script execution, memory limit is reset to default value.

Answer (score 0):

The value will return to the default value after your script execution.

You can also set your limit to `-1` in order to tell PHP that your script can use all the necessary memory.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it is a poor practice, you got to do what you have to do. If you need more memory, that's the way to do it. You might also need to increase `max_execution_time`.

That being said, you might want to check your 'memoryIntensive' functions, and optimize things there.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
```

It will use as per require memory and will not return any error or notice related to memory side.